# Getting PHAsset modification date

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I'm writing a camera roll backup tool and i'm using asset modification times as a check for if the file should be backed up or not. Here's how i'm fetching things:

```
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

for (PHAsset *asset in result)
{
    // get modification date with [asset modificationDate] timeIntervalSince1970]
}
```

It works kinda OK, but here's the **problem**: if an already backed up image is opened in photos app just to view it - modification date changes. There is no editing involved or anything like that - just a mere fact of viewing an image sets the date to something else. Why is it doing this and is there a way around it?

Comment: Why are you checking if modified? Are you modifying the image after you back it up? Why don't you have a date when the last backup has been made, and if any item has been created after that date, you back it up?

Comment: @DeryckLucian that's exactly why i'm checking for modification date - i take some photos, back them up and later i retouch them and back them up again. So creation date is not a solution to this situation.

Comment: @Marius, do you get any solution for this? I am also facing same problem. Modification date get changed every time I fetch PHAsset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can solve the problem.

```
let adjustmentResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset).filter { $0.type == .adjustmentData }
            
print("adjustmentResources = \(adjustmentResources)")

if adjustmentResources.count > 0 {


}
```

if adjustmentResources.count is greater then 0. Then it is modified otherwise not.